# Redirect attachment URL

Tags: redirect, attachments

Is anyone able to Redirect the following permalink URL for me?

The URL that WordPress is: `http://example.com/?attachment_id=411`

I would like to redirect it to new structure i do it, The following code not work with me in old URL:

```
/* add new rewrite rule */
function attachment_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $rule = array(
        'media/(.+)' => 'index.php?attachment=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rule + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'attachment_rewrite' );

/* redirect standard wordpress attachments urls to new format */
function redirect_old_attachment() {
    global $wp;

    if( !preg_match( '/^media\/(.*)/', $wp->request ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/media/' . $wp->query_vars['attachment'] ) , 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_attachment' );
/**/
function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    return home_url( '/media/' . $post->post_name );
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

So we  need when open `http://example.com/?attachment_id=411` , redirect it to `http://example.com/media/post-title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in code, htaccess, or go the fastest way to get it done reliably using a redirection plugin.

Here are three redirection plugins vetted by WordPress VIP:

https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/wpcom-legacy-redirector/

https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/external-permalinks-redux/

And here's a link to the one I use on sites:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

(glance at the number of active installs 400,000+)